# Get a copy of some function(s) from another python file in my current python file. [more than just calling of functions from another source file]

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, copy

**Path :- d:\competitive_programming\**
**Folder contents:- `algorithms.py` and `my_submittion.py`**

`algorithms.py` contains useful functions like:- *Function1(a, b)* , *Function2()*, etc.

When working *locally* I can use functions in `algorithms.py` in `my_submittion.py` using:-

```
from algorithms import Function1, Function2
processed_number = Function1(x, y)
```

But the same code will not work if I move it(`my_submittion.py`) to another folder or use it as my submittion(on codeforces/topcoder).
For that to work I have to make changes in my code(in `my_submittion.py`) like:-

```
def Function1(a, b):
    ...

processed_number = Function1(x, y)
```

That is I have to *manually copy* Function1() from `algorithms.py` to `my_submittion.py` and after that I shall be able to use that script file in different folder or use that file as my submittion(on topcoder or codeforces).

**My Question is:-**
How can I skip that part of manually copying of specific function(s) from one python file to another?
Is there any function in-built in python that can help me to achieve that task, preferably:-

```
class_or_function_copier(path_to_file, function1[, function2[, function3[,...])

# path_to_file = algorithms  (or d:\competitive_programming\algorithms.py)
# function1 = Function1
# function2 = Function2

'''
class_or_function_copier() automatically copies specified function(s) or class(es)
from a give source file to current file
'''

processed_number = Function1(x, y)
```

And after 1st run it may automatically create changes to `my_submittion.py` and make it:-

```
def Function1(a, b):
    ...

processed_number = Function1(x, y)
```

====================
Probably like **Linker** in C/Cpp which can make Final executable from multiple source files:-

```
cd "d:\competitive_programming\" ; if ($?) { gcc algorithms.c my_submittion.c -o submittion_file } ; if ($?) { .\submittion_file }
```

Till now I have written one python script to eliminate manual coping part but it will be much helpful if there is any in-built function to do so (if any).

Comment: Are you trying to do this with my_submittion.py in the parent directory, because if so, I believe that you can do `from foldername.algoritims import Function1, Function2`

Comment: @as11 Thanks. But both `algorithms.py` and `my_submittion.py` are in SAME folder... and the method you mentioned will work locally (as long as both the files are together) but if (using the method that you mentioned) I separate them from each-other the script will crash. Also using this method I can not use `my_submittion.py` as my submittion as it will always need `algorithms.py` with it to work..

Comment: From what I am understanding, you want to copy the functions from algorithims.py and have them permanently in my_submittion.py. Is that correct?

Comment: @as11 Yes exactly. But I don't want to do that manually, also I want to copy only some of the functions/classes from `algorithms.py` and NOT the whole content of `algorithms.py` as that is too large content and also a major part of that content is not required in `my_submittion.py`. In my question I've mentioned what I've done till now to eliminate manual copying part. Also I've mentioned what type of functionality I'm searching for (if there is any).

Comment: After doing some research, I have not been able to find anything. I do not believe that there is a way to do this due to the fact that in a regular use case, you could either import from another file in the same directory or simply just write the code. I have skimmed through this website and although I did not personally find anything, maybe it is useful to you. https://realpython.com/python-import/

Comment: @as11 Thanks! The link you provided is very helpful, I got to know new things...But there also I didn't find any type of functionality I'm searching for, I also think that there's no such functionality.

Comment: There likely isn't something that fits your use case unless someone decided to create a package/library for that certain use case mainly due to the fact that regularly, people use the methods of importing from another file and just simply writing the code. I personally believe that the best option is to simply just write the code within the file that you have to submit.

Answer (score 0):

You can just add the directory of `algorithms.py` to your path and then import any function you want from it to another script. Try this at the top of `my_submittion.py`:

```
import sys
sys.path.append('/path/to/algorithms.py/') # e.g. 'D:/competitive_programming/'

from algorithms import Function1, Function2
```

Comment: Thanks (I think you forgot one of the required two of the argument in sys.path.insert() in your answer).This method will make my program independently run from from any path or folder ON MY SYSTEM, BUT while making submittion to online plateform(s) it will not work as in Cloud they will not have directory of `algorithms.py` in path of their System.

Comment: You're right, I was thinking of `sys.path.append()`, fixed now. In the cloud you'd have to retrieve the directory of `algorithms.py` and add it to `path`. If the directory is static that's straight forward, otherwise you can search for the file in `my_submittion.py`.

Comment: Again Thanks for this helpful tip and obviously this method will make my job done if I am working on my project and have MY OWN cloud plateform in DRY way. But if considered in terms of submittion to  online competitive programming plateforms like Codeforces or Topcoder where I can submit ONLY SINGLE source file, in that case some different way/method is needed. Although Thanks!